# How can I make a resizable GUI with Java swing?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager, null-layout-manager

Hi :) I'm making my first GUI with Java swing, and I have a problem: when I change window dimension, "internal components" don't change their size.
I use absolute layout, it may be an important thing to know.

Comment: Which layout manager are you using? I can't help you without knowing a bit about what you have

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html

Comment: I thought absolute was a layout manager. In this case I'm not using a layout manager

Comment: If you're just getting started I highly recommend switching to using JavaFX.  It's newer, faster, easier, and the Layout managers don't suck like Swing's do.  But if you're going to use Swing I'd use GridBagLayout: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html

Comment: Without a doubt, you need to use a LayoutManager.  This is exactly what they’re for.  Read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/ to learn how to use them.

Comment: Another good article for learning is [Effective Layout Management](http://javadude.com/articles/layouts/).

Answer (score 2):

Absolute layout means that you are using absolutely defined constraints about position size e.t.c. To create resizable GUI. you need to use more "flexible" layouts.

One simple option to start is BorderLayout. Hovewer you have to leverage use of panels in this case.

[Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html)

Another possibility may be the [Grid bag](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) layout but that often involves more work to do.

Answer (score -1):

You can solve this problem by using the MigLayout in combination with the WindowsBuilder. This is a WYSIWIG editor for SWT and Swing Layouts. But BorderLayout and GridBag Layout can srink and grow as well.